# Make a bootable USB program installer

Tags: windows, usb, dos

I'm trying to make an installer for a program and for that program to work I need to alter a few important windows files

I'm trying to make it like this:

plug in the usb

boot from the usb

wait for the installer to finish

boot windows and taaada program installed

I used all kinds of variations of Ms-Dos to do this but all of them don't copy my program's files or fail at something else

Any idea how to make something similar ?

Comment: MS-DOS doesn't understand the NTFS file system used by Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [NTFSDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFSDOS) if you want to keep being in DOS, or you could use some Linux distribution and mount the harddrives partition that way.

Comment: can you recommend me a linux distro ?

Comment: @user9699066 if you come from a DOS background I think you would prefer [Slackware](http://www.slackware.com/).